# Integrate a google map javascript API into blogger

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, blogger

I'm pulling my hair with Blogger and Google Maps API.

This is what I've done :

In the Template editor I added in the customize->Advanced->Add your CSS :

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
```

Then in the Header of the template I added just before the `</head>`:

`<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAXprv_TXEju4E-phldszJrt2VNbxfIMkU' type='text/javascript'>
    </script>`

And Finally I tried to use the Right Bar widget HTML/Javascript and past in the HTML editor :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

You can see the result here :

http://f4eor.blogspot.com

Nothing works but the entire code works well in a simple HTML page created by notepad on my computer.

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Looks like it is working now (map is loading, excluding CSS issues)?

Comment: What is the desired result on the page you linked guillaume? What's not working? The map is appearing.

Comment: Hi Guys, The Map is not loading it's in the RIGHT bar, it's written MAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a fixed height (e.g. `height: 150px;`)

Comment: I'll try to put it in the CSS style and see.